# Problems installing Grunt.js

Tags: node.js, terminal, gruntjs, npm

Been at this for a couple nights now, trying to get Grunt.js to work on my mac.

I've installed Homebrew, Node.js, npm... but when I try to install grunt-cli I get an error.

Im running in my terminal: `npm install -g grunt-cli`

The error is `-bash: npm: command not found`

I've been searching forever trying to figure out what this means.  I've deleted all instances of node I could find and re-installed.

When I run npm -v I get `-bash: npm: command not found`

What is going on?  I need help.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you install node via Homebrew?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689) may fix your issue.

Comment: Tried that external link too. Still the same thing.

Comment: UPDATE: Figured it out, turns out it was a problem with node.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer. It will be helpful for people who've been in your situation. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Turns out I had to reinstall Node and make sure my file paths were correct again.